ld: framework 'Alamofire' not found for visionOS
I am experiencing an issue with building the project for visionOS.
The build is working fine on iOS, app is running as expected. But when I try to build it for visionOD (Native) it gives me the error:

ld: framework 'Alamofire' not found

I've tried to comment everything in the code using
#if os(visionOS)

#else
  all the code here...
#endif

But with no success. I am clueless at the moment. Any help would be great. I just want to run an empty screen for Apple Vision Pro.

The "ld" (load) in your error log is telling you that it's a build config issue around the Alamofire library: wrong target, wrong library version, wrong frameworks path. Perhaps you're using a too-old version of Alamofire? You'll need 5.8.1 or higher, per https://forums.swift.org/t/alamofire-5-8-1-released/68088.

And 5.9.1 if you're using CocoaPods, as Alamofire didn't have an explicit visionOS declaration for it until then. (Swift Package Manager automatically supports new platforms.)

One more question, Is there any way that we can use pods for iOS Build but do not use anything from pods for Vision Os Build?

If visionOS and iOS are in different targets, you can set different values in "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content". I expect you could even mix Swift Package Manager and CocoaPods in one target. But...that feels painfully complicated to me, since CocoaPods wants to control the xcworkspace. I don't see any advantage to doing it that way. I suggest you rip off the band-aid in one shot and move everything to Swift Package Manager so that you're not chasing down fixes for libraries that haven't been updated in ages.

Thanks for your valuable feedback, this should be the approach, :)
